# Direct link to latest secondary file on SourceForge

Tags: sourceforge

I have a SourceForge project that contains two files. One is the default download zip file and the other is a secondary zip file that not everyone is going to need.

I would like to publish a link to that secondary file, however I would like that link to always point to the latest version. Is that possible?

---

The project is tSQLt: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tsqlt/files/tsqlt/

The main download file is tSQLt.zip. The second zip file is tSQLtSnippets(SQLPrompt).zip.

I can get a direct link to any particular version like this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tsqlt/files/tsqlt/V1.0.4941.23369/tSQLtSnippets%28SQLPrompt%29.zip/download

I can get a direct link to the latest main download file like this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tsqlt/files/latest/download

However, any combination of the two that I can think of either fails or downloads the main download file instead.

Comment: What's the URL of your project?

Comment: See edit above.